# File truncated while editing with nautilus ftp and sublime

Tags: server, nautilus, ftp, sublime-text

I was connected to ftp session to a server via nautilus ftp (Connect to Server option in File tab). So after editing the file in sublime, I was trying to save the file but sublime hanged in between and I closed the sublime windows after closing the files in it and restarted the ftp connection, however to my surprise the file which I was editing was truncated.

Is there any option to recover the contents of file?

Thanks